# Alternative to MoreObjects in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, guava, tostring

I want to get rid of this dependency: `import com.google.common.base.MoreObjects;`

Is there any simple and/or elegant way to rewrite the following `toString()` function using Java 8 native functions?

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return MoreObjects
    .toStringHelper(this)
    .add("userId", this.userId)
    .add("timestamp", this.timestamp)
    .toString();
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) from `java.util` package.

Example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new StringJoiner(", ", ClassName.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
    .add("userId=" + userId)
    .add("timestamp=" + timestamp)
    .toString();
}
```

Comment: I will chose this solution for its clarity and elegance. I find `StringBuilder` less self-explanatory comparing it with `StringJoiner`. The plain `str1 + str2` is too low-level (and verbose) for me. Thanks you.

Comment: Be aware, that `Class#getSimpleName()` is quiet slow.

Answer (score 7):

I don't see any reason to use this `toStringHelper` even prior to Java 8. The plain implementation is not longer:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getSimpleName()+"["
          +"userId: "+this.userId+", "
          +"timestamp: "+this.timestamp
          +"]";
}
```

Comment: This will (EDIT: *may*) generate more garbage than the `StringBuilder` solution.

Comment: @sdgfsdh, do you have any proofs?

Comment: @sdgfsdh I think the compiler will optimize it and the generated bytecode will be the same as using StringBuilder (since the + are not in loops)

Comment: Yes, it depends on the compiler. `StringBuilder` will be good on any compiler, however.

Comment: @Tunaki, actually if [indify Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8085796) JEP will successfully move forward to Java-9, my solution would actually be more performant than `StringBuilder` solution.

Comment: @sdgfsdh, could you please name at least one compiler which provides less effective solution?

Comment: Even if you encounter a compiler creating `concat` based code, the garbage would not be bigger than that of the original `MoreObjects` builder code. And it would be still unlikely that you ever notice a performance difference; if the method ever becomes a hotspot, the JVM knows how to optimize sequences of `concat` operations…

Answer (score 4):

Why not build the String yourself? The code is simple to write and to understand, without using any Java 8 specific features.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(getClass().getSimpleName()).append('{')
    sb.append("userId=").append(userId);
    sb.append(", timestamp=").append(timestamp);
    return sb.append('}').toString();
}
```

Comment: Does `sb.append("MyMap-String-Integer=").append(myMapStrInt)` produce a nice json-like formating of my map?

Comment: @Costin, most of maps have properly implemented `toString()` method, so yes.

Answer (score 3):

Just featuring a pretty cool solution to let IntelliJ Idea generate the toString with StringJoiner: https://gist.github.com/vlastikcz/6a3b5c158bdb7bf6e9fd (thanks a lot to the author)
Add the code to toString templates: press Alt+Insert, select toString, then select Settings besides Templates, add with the Plus sign:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons-lang3 has ToString helpers if that dependency is ok:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this).
    append("name", name).
    append("age", age).
    append("smoker", smoker).
    toString();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(this);
}
```

See https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/package-summary.html